# Execute module as script breaks imports

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a Python program with the "structure" shown at the end.

The problem is that actions should be able to be executed as scripts as well (I've already included a main in them). When I try to execute `DummyAction.py` imports keep complaining they can't find `misc`.

How can I use `DummyAction.py` as a script and still use the functions in `utils.py`?

`DummyAction.py` contains a class called `DummyActionClass`, and the same for `DummyTrigger.py`. In `utils.py` there are several functions that both actions and triggers use and `MMD.py` contains the main.

```
/MMD
├── __init__.py
├── MMD.py
├── /actions
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── DummyAction.py
├── /misc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── utils.py
└── /triggers
    ├── DummyTrigger.py
    └── __init__.py
```

The import in `DummyAction.py` and `DummyTrigger.py` is:

```
from misc import utils
```

And the error is:

```
File "DDM/actions/DummyAction.py", line 11, in <module>
    from misc import utils
ImportError: No module named misc
```

Comment: Do you call the script with something like `python MMD/actions/DummyAction.py`?

Comment: @RikPoggi Yes, I would like to call the script like that.

Comment: Could you show the imports for each file and the error that you get?

Comment: @RikPoggi There, I added the imports and the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seen the updated question, I think the problem is that you should do the import including the root of your dependecies tree: MMD.

So they should all look like:

```
from MMD.misc import utils
```

And also you need to call `python` with the `-m` option:

```
python -m  MMD.actions.DummyAction
```

**Edit:** You said that `MMD.py` contains the main but it can't be your executable, and that's because is a module (is inside a directory with an `__init__.py` file). `MMD` is like your library so you need the executable to be outside and use such library.

You can find [[here]](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html) some guidelines on how to organize your project.

If you can change you project structure I'll suggest to do it like this:

```
MMD/
├── runner.py
└──  mmd
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    ├── /actions
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── DummyAction.py
    ├── /misc
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── utils.py
    └── /triggers
        ├── DummyTrigger.py
        └── __init__.py
```

Then in **any file** inside the `mmd` directory **every** import should start with `mmd`, for example:

```
from mmd.misc import utils
from mmd.actions import DummyActions
```

And you put your main code that now is inside `MMD.py` inside a `Main` class in `main.py`, with something like:

```
# main.py
from mmd.misc import utils

class Main:
    def start_session(self):
        utils.function()
        # etc ...
```

And then in `runner.py` you do something like:

```
# runner.py
from mmd.main import Main

cli = Main()
cli.start_session()
```

This way inside the `MMD` directory calling `python runner.py` you would execute your code, and you can also make executable `runner.py` so a simply `./runner.py` will run your code.
And run your module with:

```
python -m  mmd.actions.DummyAction
```

I'd do it like this, becasue this way is open to future implementation (and is almost like in the line guides).

If instead you can't, then you can give it a try at removing `__init__.py` from the `MMD` directory.

Comment: I did try that but when I run: `python DDM/actions/DummyAction.py` I get the same error: `No module named MMD.misc`

Comment: Sorry MMD, typo. But still get the same message.

Comment: @mcieec: Ok, everything should be fine using `python -m` *(I don't know why I didn't noticed this before)* otherwise your dependecises are not loaded, but you get a simple file execution. Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: I've tried `from MMD.misc import utils` and it works fine when calling `python -m  MMD.actions.DummyAction`.
However in `MMD.py` then I can't call `from actions import DummyAction` it throws `ImportError: cannot import name DummyAction`

Comment: Can you take a look to my own answer, see if it makes sense?

Comment: @mcieec: You should use `from MMD.actions import DummyAction` even inside `MMD`. Looking at your answer it seems that your `MMD.py` not also contain the main code, but you want it to be your executable. That is not a good practice, because your executable should be outside your library. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I've just implemented the solution and it works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a directory structure you're talking about, in which case python doesn't know where to look for utils.py - it tries the local directory, a few places in the path then gives up. It's simple enough to modify the path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/MMD/misc")
import utils
```

and you should be away.

Comment: Ok, but could I use relative paths? I tried : `sys.path.append("../../")` and it does not work.

Comment: No, you can't use relative paths, they'll be assessed on where you are when you invoke it, not where it is. You can use sys.argv[0] to find out what script is being run and where it is, but that's getting a little off topic...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a "workarround"

```
try:
    #When executing from the main
    from misc import utils
except:
    #When executing as a standalone script
    from MMD.misc import utils
```

that allows to:

- Call the module as a script (while using other modules): `python -m MMD.actions.DummyAction`
- Call the main program and use the module: `python MMD/MMD.py`

Although I'm not sure if it's strictly correct to use a *try - except* block with an import, so feel free to add comments or other solutions.

The **complete** solution would be:

`MMD.main`

```
from misc import utils
from actions import DummyAction

class MMD():

    def __init__(self):
        a = DummyAction.DummyActionClass()
        utils.foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = MMD()
```

Then in `actions/DummyAction.py`:

```
try:
    #When executing from the main
    from misc import utils
except:
    #When executing as a standalone script
    from MMD.misc import utils

class DummyActionClass():

    def __init__(self):
        utils.foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = DummyActionClass()
```

And finally in `misc/utils.py`:

```
def foo():
    print "Foo was called"
```

Comment: This works although I marked Rik Poggi's solution as correct because I belive it's better and does not rely on a try-except block for the imports.